# Extending lines using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-pro, line, connection

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.6.1.

I have massive map of roads in multiple road files. I need to extend lines to their intersect point. Intersect tool does not seem to work to my satisfaction. Any other suggestions.

Should I combine multiple files into one?

I have a layer of points that can be extended to, but could not find anything.

[image]

Comment: Do the lines need to stay on the road network? If so, you should probably add network analysis as a tag.

Comment: It would be nice if you drew provided also an image of what you expect to happen. So you have points to which you want to extend the lines to, but how would you specify which lines do you want to extend and to which points?

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Pro has two ways to extend polylines that you have not mentioned in your question:

1. You can [Extend or trim a polyline feature](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/extend-or-trim-polyline-features.htm) when editing:

> In the **Modify Features** pane, the **Extend or Trim tool** extends a
> selected line feature to an existing feature boundary or trims it
> where they intersect. The tool pane contains one multitool that
> extends or trims a line, and two preset tools that exclusively extend
> and trim.

2. If you have a Standard or Advanced level license, then you can use the [Extend Line (Editing)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/extend-line.htm) tool:

> This tool extends line segments to the first intersecting feature
> within a specified distance. If no intersecting feature is within the
> specified distance, the line segment will not be extended. Tool use is
> intended for quality control tasks such as cleaning up topology errors
> in features that were digitized without having set proper snapping
> environments.

Comment: Easy said. It gets stuck at 263100 element, and sits for two days.